# Order by single column using multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql

This a hard question to know how to ask properly, but here goes...

This is the basic format of my table (the actual table has many rows and multiple lang_ids):

```
----------------------------------
| id | lang_id | key    | text   |
----------------------------------
| 1  |    1    | k_foo  | foo    |
----------------------------------
| 2  |    1    | k_bar  |  bar   |
----------------------------------
| 3  |    2    | k_bar  | le bar |
----------------------------------
| 4  |    2    | k_foo  | le foo |
----------------------------------
```

What I want to do is return the rows with  `WHERE lang_id = 2` but order them by results of `WHERE lang_id = 1` like so:

```
----------------------------------
| id | lang_id | key    | text   |
----------------------------------
| 4  |    2    | k_foo  | le foo |
----------------------------------
| 3  |    2    | k_bar  | le bar |
----------------------------------
```

I am driving myself nuts trying to figure it out. I've searched for hours but keep getting results for ordering by multiple columns instead of multiple results of a single column.

I've tried joining it, unioning it, and subqueries but I either return hundreds of rows, or none!

Comment: Ho do your rows marry together?

Comment: How does ID 2 match row 4, and 1 match 3, or however that is done? What columns, what rules?

Comment: That's fine, but how do I know `bar` and `le bar` are the same thing? What is there to identify what word is a translation for another?

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Sorry, I am an idiot, I've edited it. They all have a field called 'key' which is the common denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    l2.id,
    l2.lang_id,
    l2.key,
    l2.text
FROM
    language l1
JOIN
    language l2
    ON l2.key = l1.key

WHERE
    l1.lang_id = 1
    AND
    l2.lang_id = 2
ORDER BY
    l1.id -- Replace with whatever column you actually want to order by.
```